# Can Rust lazy-load dynamically linked (.dll/.so/.dylib) crates?

Tags: rust, shared-libraries, dlopen

So, im just curious.
For example: i have a crate `my_lib` with the following code in `Cargo.toml`:

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["dylib"]
```

Then i can use the library in other crate:

```
[dependencies]
my_lib = { path = "../my_lib" }
```

This allows me to use `my_lib` in the program just like any statically-linked crate. And `my_lib` is compiled to a separate shared object.

But can rust actually lazy load dylib crates OR at least allow to still boot an executable even when required shared object is not present? By running i mean that program will be able to check that it lacks the library and will run without some features.

You might think that manually loading symbols via `dlopen` (or dlopen wrappers) is the solution. But there is the problem that in that case i cannot use types and structs and traits, etc, from the crate. I can only use loaded symbols.

What solutions, i think, might exist:

- Being able to pass some `RUSTFLAGS`, something remotely like `/DELAYLOAD` in windows.
- Being able to use types from other crates without linking those crates at all. Just manually creating wrappers for each function.
- Being able to manually create some sort of rust compiler plugin, that will in the end of the compilation collect a list of all the symbols and types and generate a wrapper-crate based on this.
- Some code-generating crate that generates wrappers of other crates. Those wrappers would manually load symbols from other crates, while still providing functions and types.

Do **NOT** care about being able to C-FFI types and ABI stuff. For me its acceptable to only use .dll/.so/.dylib-s that are compiled with the exact same version of the compiler, so ABI is the same.

Answer (score 3):

For the purpose of this example, I would organize the crates like this.

```
.
├── lazy_app
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
├── lazy_impl_a
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── lib.rs
├── lazy_impl_b
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── lib.rs
└── lazy_interface
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
        └── lib.rs
```

`lazy_app` is the application that needs to optionally load a crate at runtime.
`lazy_interface` defines the elements that anyone could expect from such a dynamically loaded crate: at least a trait and some utilities to obtain a dynamic object implementing this trait.
`lazy_impl_a` and `lazy_impl_b` are two examples of dynamic libraries implementing such an interface.

`lazy_interface/src/lib.rs` looks like this

```rust
/*
[dependencies]
libc = "0.2"
*/

use std::ffi::{CStr, CString};

pub trait LazyTrait {
    fn show_something(&self) -> String;
    fn do_something(&mut self);
}

pub struct LazyInterface {
    lib: *mut libc::c_void,
    make:
        fn(&[&str]) -> Result<Box<dyn LazyTrait>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>,
}
impl LazyInterface {
    pub fn load(path: &str) -> Result<Self, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        let lib_name = CString::new(path)?;
        let lib = unsafe {
            libc::dlopen(
                lib_name.as_ptr() as *const libc::c_char,
                libc::RTLD_LAZY,
            )
        };
        if lib.is_null() {
            let mut msg = format!("cannot load {:?}", path);
            Self::error_detail(&mut msg);
            Err(msg)?
        }
        let fnct_name = CString::new("make_lazy")?;
        let symb = unsafe {
            libc::dlsym(lib, fnct_name.as_ptr() as *const libc::c_char)
        };
        if symb.is_null() {
            let mut msg =
                format!("cannot find {:?} in {:?}", fnct_name, path);
            Self::error_detail(&mut msg);
            Self::close(lib);
            Err(msg)?
        }
        Ok(Self {
            lib,
            make: unsafe { std::mem::transmute(symb) },
        })
    }
    pub fn make(
        &self,
        params: &[&str],
    ) -> Result<Box<dyn LazyTrait>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        (self.make)(params)
    }
    fn error_detail(msg: &mut String) {
        let c_ptr = unsafe { libc::dlerror() };
        if !c_ptr.is_null() {
            msg.push_str(": ");
            msg.push_str(&unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(c_ptr) }.to_string_lossy());
        }
    }
    fn close(lib: *mut libc::c_void) {
        unsafe { libc::dlclose(lib) };
    }
}
impl Drop for LazyInterface {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        Self::close(self.lib);
    }
}
```

`LazyTrait` should expose everything that could be expected from a dynamically loaded crate; this example relies only on two trivial functions.
`LazyInterface` provides the boilerplate to obtain a dynamic object implementing this trait.
I used `libc::dlopen()` to keep it simple, but some other solutions might help portability.
Note that this crate is a usual `"lib"` crate.

`lazy_impl_a/src/lib.rs` and `lazy_impl_b/src/lib.rs` could be defined like this

```rust
/*
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
lazy_interface = { path = "../lazy_interface" }
*/

use lazy_interface::LazyTrait;

struct LazyA {
    a: i32,
    b: String,
}
impl LazyTrait for LazyA {
    fn show_something(&self) -> String {
        format!("LazyA with {:?} and {:?}", self.a, self.b)
    }

    fn do_something(&mut self) {
        self.b.push_str(&format!("\nchanged {}", self.a));
        self.a += 5;
        self.b.push_str(&format!(" into {}", self.a));
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn make_lazy(
    params: &[&str]
) -> Result<Box<dyn LazyTrait>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let first = *params.get(0).ok_or("missing first parameter")?;
    let second = *params.get(1).ok_or("missing second parameter")?;
    Ok(Box::new(LazyA {
        a: first.parse()?,
        b: second.to_owned(),
    }))
}
```

```rust
/*
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
lazy_interface = { path = "../lazy_interface" }
*/

use lazy_interface::LazyTrait;

struct LazyB {
    v: Vec<String>,
}
impl LazyTrait for LazyB {
    fn show_something(&self) -> String {
        format!("LazyB with {:?}", self.v)
    }

    fn do_something(&mut self) {
        self.v.push(format!("element {}", self.v.len()));
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn make_lazy(
    params: &[&str]
) -> Result<Box<dyn LazyTrait>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    Ok(Box::new(LazyB {
        v: params.iter().map(|&s| s.to_owned()).collect(),
    }))
}
```

The implementation of the trait does not have anything specific to dynamic code loading.
We just need to expose with `no_mangle` a function providing a dynamic object implementing this trait; this function **must match exactly** the prototype expected in the `LazyInterface::make` function pointer.
Note that such crates have the `"cdylib"` crate type and must be built as well as the application (the application won't build these crates because they are not part of its dependencies).

Finally, `lazy_app/src/main.rs` could be like this

```rust
/*
[dependencies]
lazy_interface = { path = "../lazy_interface" }
*/

use lazy_interface::LazyInterface;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    for lib in [
        "../lazy_impl_a/target/debug/liblazy_impl_a.so",
        "../lazy_impl_b/target/debug/liblazy_impl_b.so",
    ] {
        match LazyInterface::load(lib) {
            Ok(itf) => {
                let mut lazy = itf.make(&["123", "hello"])?;
                lazy.do_something();
                println!("~~> {}", lazy.show_something());
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("{}", e);
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
/*
~~> LazyA with 128 and "hello\nchanged 123 into 128"
~~> LazyB with ["123", "hello", "element 2"]
*/
```

Only the resources of `lazy_interface` are known, and the implementations are loaded only if they are available.

Note that all of this relies on a bunch of `unsafe` invocations.
It is very easy to introduce bugs.
For example, if the prototype of the `make_lazy` function exposed in the implementation does not match exactly what is expected in the `LazyInterface::make` function pointer, anything can happen.
Another terrible thing could happen if the `LazyInterface` is dropped in the application while some resources it created (directly or indirectly) are still in use.
This example is just an idea; it should be double-checked in order to detect anything that is or could become unsound.